# How Can I Create Post Request Using Retrofit 2.0 Android

Tags: android, json, post, request, retrofit

Hi Guys I have to create user with post method by using retrofit library I can get but I can not post Can you solve that .

This is my Json Result :

```
    {"user":[{"_id":"587c0346f8469d38a0ea46bf",
"username":"developer",
"name":"Bekir","surname":"Tura",
"tel":"023656565","age":"25",
"location_id":"_id":"587c0346f8469d38a0ea46be","il":"istanbul","ilce":"cevizlibağ"},"__v":0}]}
```

This post method is right ?

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("createUser")
    Call<User> insertuserinfo(@Field("username") String username,
                              @Field("name") String name,
                              @Field("surname") String surname,
                              @Field("tel") int tel,
                              @Field("age") int age,
                              @Field("il") String il,
                              @Field("ilce") String ilce);
```

Where is my fault ?

Comment: Do you have any error ?

Comment: no error unfortunutely but I created user without user' information